# Google Maps API Stop Working when i'm include jQuery File

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

There I used the Google Maps API and the code works for me properly. 
But when I try to add to the jQuery Libary, the map stops working.

I would appreciate your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Complex icons</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var infowindow = null;

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);


            setMarkers(map, sites);
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "loading..."
            });
            /*
            var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
            bikeLayer.setMap(map);
            */
            // Try HTML5 geolocation
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                                     position.coords.longitude);


                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        map: map,
                        position: pos,
                        content: 'Location found using HTML5.' + pos
                    });

                    map.setCenter(pos);
                }, function () {
                    handleNoGeolocation(true);
                });
            } else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleNoGeolocation(false);
            }
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
            if (errorFlag) {
                var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
            } else {
                var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
            }

            var options = {
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.321458, 34.8531),
                content: content
            };

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
            map.setCenter(options.position);
        }

        var sites = [
        ['Mount Evans', 32.32108, 34.85535, 4, 'This is Mount Evans.<h1>test</h1>'],
        ['Irving Homestead', 32.315939, 34.850630, 2, 'This is the Irving Homestead.'],
        ['Badlands National Park', 32.325890, 34.85175, 1, 'This is Badlands National Park'],
        ['Flatirons in the Spring', 32.35948, 34.85370, 3, 'These are the Flatirons in the spring.']
        ];

        function setMarkers(map, markers) {
            var image = {
                url: 'image/red-rounded04.png',
                // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
                size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32)
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var sites = markers[i];
                var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: siteLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: sites[0],
                    zIndex: sites[3],
                    html: sites[4],
                    icon: image
                });

                var contentString = "Some content";

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                    //alert(this.html);
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            }
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And when i'm try to include the jQuery File,
it's stop work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When are you including jQuery?  Before or after your map script?

Comment: In your browser's javascript console (right click in Chrome and select  "Inspect element" and the click "Console") are you seeing any errors reported when the page loads with jQuery?

Comment: Hi, i try to include Before And after, and it the same.

Comment: Jason: this is what i get in the javascript console:
-----
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no javascript-error (the mentioned message in the console is only a warning).

You have included jquery-mobile, which will modify the structure of the document when it doesn't find the expected structure.

The content (`#map-canvas`) will be wrapped in another div(with the class `.ui-page`). For this div a `height` isn't specified, the `100%` for `#map-canvas` will have no effect, because the `100%` will be calculated based on the defined `height` of the parent element(which is not defined).

You will see the map when you set the `height` of `.ui-page` too(e.g. to `100%`), but I would suggest to start by reading the [jquery-mobile-documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/pages/)